# Query Parse Image

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I wanted to draw with a query, the profile picture of my user inside a UIImageView ... This code gives me the picture but only the nick name ... Can you help me to understand where is the error?

Thank you!

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //Prepare the query to get the profile image
    //1
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    PFQuery* queryPhoto = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Foto_Profilo"];

    //2
    PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentUser];
        [queryPhoto whereKey:@"Immagine" equalTo:currentUser];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            // Verify if there are no errors
            if (!error) {

                // Retrieve Usename
                self.profileViewUsernameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]valueForKey:@"username"]] ;

                // Retrieve Photo

                PFObject* profilePhotoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Foto_Profilo"];
                PFFile* currentUserPhoto = (PFFile *)[profilePhotoObject objectForKey:@"Immagine"];
                UIImageView* currentUserImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:currentUserPhoto.getData]];



                [self.showfoto addSubview:currentUserImage];
            } else {
                NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [errorAlertView show];

            }

        } ];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear from the question but I guess you get the name and not the image.

`profilePhotoObject` is a new empty object so when you request `objectForKey:@"Immagine"` from it you get nil.

You define `queryPhoto` but never actually execute it. Execute it and handle the result separate to your current block.

---

You create 2 queries. You execute 1 and don't use the result. You don't execute the other (the one that looks to actually have the image).

Let's try replacing your current query with:

```
        [queryPhoto findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        // Verify if there are no errors
        if (objects.count >= 1) {

            // Retrieve Usename
            self.profileViewUsernameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]valueForKey:@"username"]] ;

            // Retrieve Photo

            PFObject* profilePhotoObject = objects[0]
            PFFile* currentUserPhoto = (PFFile *)[profilePhotoObject objectForKey:@"Immagine"];
            UIImageView* currentUserImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:currentUserPhoto.getData]];
```

Note that this uses the other query you created and uses the result of executing the query.

Comment: Thank you very much Wain .... Unfortunately, I am a novice in this ... could you explain better or make me notice the error in the code? How could I retrieve the saved profile picture and show it in a specific UIView Image

Comment: Wain Hello, I replaced the piece of code you've kindly soggerito and now seems to respond with Error Alert View and returns the image ... Surely I'm doing something wrong ... I'm sorry for your patience :)

Comment: Solved! Wain Sorry I forgot to disable the query above: D. .. Now you see the image and the nickname just can not seem to block the size of the UI Image View to be able to display in small format

Comment: Set the image view `frame` after you create it and before you add it as a subview.

Comment: Set and now it 's all ok! The only problem is that now I see that the image is not that of the current user, it displays the first image I uploaded to the server: (to understand why, but the code is specified Current User

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
PFQuery *queryUser = [PFUser query];
[queryUser whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];
[queryUser getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){

        //Cargo la imagen de la celda
        PFFile *theImage = [object objectForKey:@"userImage"];
        NSData *imageData = [theImage getData];
        UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        if (profileImage == nil) {
            _imgProfile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto.png"];
        } else {
            _imgProfile.image = profileImage;
        }


}];
```